# Ember.Binding.transform migration to latest code

Tags: ember.js

Ember.Binding.transform has been removed or replaced in the latest ember.  I have a number of bindings that take this form:

```
valueBinding: Ember.Binding.transform({
  to: function(value, binding) {
    //return something
  },
  from: function(value, binding) {
    //return something
  }
}).from('parentView.content.finishBy'),
```

Can anyone advise me how I should update my code to the new regime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your computed property definition to `Ember.computed`, see 
http://jsbin.com/awufuv/edit#source:

```js
Ember.computed.finishBy = function() {
  return Ember.computed('parentView.content.finishBy', function(key) {
    var finishBy = Ember.getPath(this, 'parentView.content.finishBy');
    return finishBy === 'now';
  }).cacheable();
};
```

You can then use it like this:

```js
App.obj = Ember.Object.create({
  parentView: {
    content: {
      finishBy: 'now'
    }
  },
  finishProp: Ember.computed.finishBy()
});
```

See more examples in https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/computed.js#L417-434

---

Just to be clear: you're not forced to add your custom computed property to `Ember.computed`. You can basically declare the function anywhere in your code. Now that I think about it, you might want to add your helper to your applications namespace instead of adding / poluting it to `Ember`. But that's just an issue of personal preference.

Comment: Ember.DateTime has the following reference to transform:

Ember.Binding.dateTime = function(format) {
  return this.transform(function(value, binding) {
    return value ? value.toFormattedString(format) : null;
  });
};

Do you think this should be a computed property also?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good discussion on the [original commit](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/7ae011753e595086287f06733028b260e0526847) on how to update your code.

However, in your case, I think you could just use a computed property:

```
value: function(key, value){
  if(arguments.length===1){
    //return something
  } else{
    //set and return something
  }
}).property('parentView.content.finishBy')
```